# Recommended method for getting character positions of all HTML tags in a document

Tags: java, html, parsing, uima

So regular expressions [may have side-effects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/577298). What, then, is the preferred method of getting the start and end character positions of all HTML tags in a document? Parsing libraries such as Jsoup and NekoHTML don't seem to provide this information, even [XMLLocator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/xml/sax/Locator.html) doesn't seem to apply, since it only provides the *end* of the current document event.

I'm not interested in the type or name of tag, any of its attributes, or stripping anything out of the text. I just want to know where they start and where they end.

For purposes of this question, it can be assumed that the source HTML is valid.

Comment: Make sure it's a valid HTML first

Comment: Hmm, I was assuming that was implied, but I've clarified that in the question.

Comment: Your question sounds like a means to an end. What business problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Isn't "a means to an end" a required attribute for all programming questions? :) Anyway, the application involves annotating HTML as part of an Apache UIMA annotator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was curious myself, so I found this parser: http://jericho.htmlparser.net/

```
public void testJericho() throws IOException{

    Source source=new Source(new URL("http://example.com/"));
    List<Element> elementList=source.getAllElements();
    for (Element element : elementList) {
        printElement(element);
    }

}

public void printElement(Element element) {
    List<Element> children = element.getChildElements();
    for(Element child: children) 
        printElement(child);

    System.out.println(element.getName() + " start: " + element.getBegin());
    System.out.println(element.getName() + " end: " + element.getEnd());        
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! I'd looked at Jericho, but managed to miss that feature. I'm only interested in annotating the tags, not the contents, so I'm also making use of the Element.getStartTag() and Element.getEndTag() functions.